Bootstrap Hamburger menu shifts right on Mobile on clicking causing horizontal scrolling and whitespace
I have a website built with Bootstrap, and it works fine on desktop. However, when I open it on a mobile device(android + chrome), the hamburger menu shifts to the right after clicking it for the first time, causing the entire page to create horizontal scrolling and a band of whitespace below shifted hamburger menu. It is visible correctly when it loads for the first time. I am also attaching screengrabs and the url is https://www.globalmeds.in/

I cannot replicate it using developer tools on desktop. It works fine at every resolution in chrome desktop.

Please see [ask]. You're required to show some code at a minimum, and it's not difficult to create a demo using the editor.

The issue is not caused by the hamburger menu. To confirm that, open the website, from Chrome dev tools, switch to mobile view (responsive view), and you will see that the scrollbar appears before even clicking the menu.
As I expected it's from AOS Library because it changes the positions for your elements until you scroll to them, then it will move the elements to their real place. You will see this issue especially (but not limited to) with any element that has an AOS class that manipulate the x-axis like data-aos="fade-right" or data-aos="fade-left".
You could solve this issue by adding overflow-x: hidden; to each container (parent) of an animated element. In your case, you can add the following:
.container-xl {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

However, I don't recommend this way because it will affect all .container-xl
in your site and that may cause some undesired results.
Instead, you could create a helper CSS class:
.overflow-x-hidden {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

Then use it wherever needed.
Some folks would say why don't you utilize bootstrap ready-made class overflow-hidden but that will make overflow-y: hidden; as well which is not necessary and also might result in unwanted behavior.
P.S
There is an open issue already on a similar issue on AOS GitHub repo.
Hava a look at it
